# Avoid "warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast] " in a _generic macro

Tags: c, macros, polymorphism, warnings

The following code works as intended,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define GEN__INTEGER_ 0 
#define GEN__STRING_ 1 
#define GEN__U8_ARRAY_ 2
#define GEN__U16_ARRAY_ 3
#define GEN__U32_ARRAY_ 4

#define INTEGER_EQUAL(observed,expected)        (observed == expected)
#define STRING_EQUAL(observed,expected)         (strcmp((char *)observed, (char *)expected) == 0)
#define U8_ARRAY_EQUAL(observed,expected)       (memcmp((uint8_t *)observed, (uint8_t *)expected, sizeof(expected)/sizeof(uint8_t)) == 0)
#define U16_ARRAY_EQUAL(observed,expected)      (memcmp((uint16_t *)observed, (uint16_t *)expected, sizeof(expected)/sizeof(uint16_t)) == 0)
#define U32_ARRAY_EQUAL(observed,expected)      (memcmp((uint32_t *)observed, (uint32_t *)expected, sizeof(expected)/sizeof(uint32_t)) == 0)
#define GENERIC_EQUAL(observed,expected)        do{ \
                                                   printf("Is "#observed" equal to "#expected" ? "); \
                                                   if( _Generic( \
                                                   (observed)+0, \
                                                   default:   INTEGER_EQUAL(observed,expected), \
                                                   char *:    STRING_EQUAL(observed,expected), \
                                                   uint8_t *: U8_ARRAY_EQUAL(observed,expected), \
                                                   uint16_t *: U16_ARRAY_EQUAL(observed,expected), \
                                                   uint32_t *: U32_ARRAY_EQUAL(observed,expected) \
                                                   )) {printf("[OK]\n");} else {printf("[FAILS]\n");}\
                                                }while(0)

#define INTEGER_PRINT(data)     printf("integer : %d\n",data)
#define STRING_PRINT(data)      printf("string : %s\n",data);
#define U8_ARRAY_PRINT(data)    do{ \
                                    uint8_t gen_buf_[sizeof(data)]; \
                                    memcpy(gen_buf_,(uint8_t*)data,sizeof(data)); \
                                    printf("arr_u8 : "); \
                                    for(uint8_t _igen_ = 0; _igen_<sizeof(data)/sizeof(uint8_t);_igen_++) \
                                    {  \
                                       printf("%d,",gen_buf_[_igen_]); \
                                    } \
                                    printf("\n"); \
                                }while(0)

#define GENERIC_PRINT(data)     do{\
                                    switch(_Generic( \
                                            (data)+0, \
                                            default:   GEN__INTEGER_, \
                                            char *:    GEN__STRING_, \
                                            uint8_t *: GEN__U8_ARRAY_, \
                                            uint16_t *: GEN__U16_ARRAY_, \
                                            uint32_t *: GEN__U32_ARRAY_ \
                                          )){  \
                                        case GEN__STRING_: STRING_PRINT(data); break;\
                                        case GEN__U8_ARRAY_: U8_ARRAY_PRINT(data); break;\
                                        case GEN__U16_ARRAY_: U8_ARRAY_PRINT(data); break; \
                                        case GEN__U32_ARRAY_: U8_ARRAY_PRINT(data); break; \
                                        default: INTEGER_PRINT(data); break; \
                                    } \
                                } while(0)

int main()
{
    uint8_t integ1 = 0;
    uint8_t integ2 = 1;
    GENERIC_EQUAL(integ1,integ2);
    GENERIC_PRINT(integ1);

    char string1[]="abc";
    char string2[]="abc";
    GENERIC_EQUAL(string1,string2);
    GENERIC_PRINT(string1);

    uint8_t array0[]={1,2};
    uint8_t array1[]={1,2};
    uint8_t array2[]={1,3};
    uint8_t array3[]={1,2,3,4};
    GENERIC_EQUAL(array1,array0);
    GENERIC_EQUAL(array1,array2);
    GENERIC_EQUAL(array1,array3);
    GENERIC_PRINT(array1);
    GENERIC_PRINT(array2);
    GENERIC_PRINT(array3);

    return 0;
}
```

but produces the following warnings:

```
main.c:16:78: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]                                   
main.c:25:63: note: in expansion of macro ‘U8_ARRAY_EQUAL’                                                                      
main.c:69:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘GENERIC_EQUAL’                                                                        
main.c:17:57: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]                                   
[...]
main.c:81:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘GENERIC_PRINT’                                                                        
main.c:35:53: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]                
[...]                                                                                                     
main.c:31:40: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint8_t * {aka unsigned char *}’ [  
-Wformat=]                                                                                                                      
main.c:70:50: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTEGER_PRINT’                                                                       
main.c:97:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘GENERIC_PRINT’
```

Is there a way to avoid the firsts warnings [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]?

I can't call without the casts...

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but symbols beginning with double underscore (like e.g. `__GEN__INTEGER`) are reserved and should not be created by you. See e.g. [this reserved identifiers reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue here is on how you use pointers in each macro.

For example, the macro `U8_ARRAY_EQUAL(integ1, integ2)` expands to:

```
(memcmp((uint8_t *)integ1, (uint8_t *)integ2, sizeof(integ2)/sizeof(uint8_t)) == 0)
```

Which means you are casting the value of integ1 and integ2 to pointers, and not their memory addresses.

A fix for this would be defining the macros as:

```
#define U8_ARRAY_EQUAL(observed,expected) (memcmp((uint8_t *)&observed, (uint8_t *)&expected, sizeof(expected)/sizeof(uint8_t)) == 0)
```

Notice the `&`? This way you are actually telling `memcmp` to compare what the memory region which contains `integ1` and `integ2`, instead of casting their values and trying to use them as memory addresses.

Comment: thanks, i just need to fix the last warning now (main.c:32:40: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=] )

Comment: the best way is to stop use the `generic`. it is fine to play with - but unacceptable in any real code